# CSS sprite animation with a large sprite freezes at the start

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sprite

I have 2 sprite animations in which there are a lot of frames:

- Idle - 5632x5632 pixels (678 Kb)
- Action - 7168x7168 pixels (879 kb)

My CSS:

```
.idle {
  --animFrames: 11;
  --animDuration: 4s;
  background-image: url("idle.png");
  animation: idlev var(--animDuration) steps(var(--animFrames)) infinite, idleh calc(var(--animDuration) / var(--animFrames)) steps(var(--animFrames)) infinite;
}
@keyframes idlev {
  0% {background-position-y: 0px;}
  100% {background-position-y: -5632px;}
}
@keyframes idleh {
  0% {background-position-x: 0px;}
  100% {background-position-x: -5632px;}
}

.action {
  --animFrames: 14;
  --animDuration: 5s;
  background-image: url("action.png");
  animation: actionv var(--animDuration) steps(var(--animFrames)) infinite, actionh calc(var(--animDuration) / var(--animFrames)) steps(var(--animFrames)) infinite;
}
@keyframes actionv {
  0% {background-position-y: 0px;}
  100% {background-position-y: -7168px;}
}
@keyframes actionh {
  0% {background-position-x: 0px;}
  100% {background-position-x: -7168px;}
}
```

When I change the class to another animation with the following code, I see a small frieze at the beginning of the animation:

```
$('.animation-container').removeClass('idle').addClass('action');
```

When changing to idle and again to action, it no longer observes a frieze. If I use 3 animations, for example, otherAction, and go along the path "idle -> action -> idle -> otherAction -> idle -> action" then in action I see the frieze again (by the way in "otherAction" too).
Perhaps this is due to the fact that my sprites are too large? I tried to preload them so that they didn't download when animation start, but that didn't help.
Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S. Sorry, but I can’t upload sprites for your tests, since I promised not to provide them to third parties  :(

Comment: The problem is that if you change the url while changing class, it will trigger download of the file. Use preloading to the file so it's downloaded and in memory before animation starts.

Comment: @jcubic I tried to do this in several ways, but none helped. Maybe there is another way that I don't know about? May I ask you for an example?

Comment: Can you show what did you try, how do you preload the image? You have few ways of doing this for instance you can create hidden image tag with both images.

Comment: I tried this solution for JS and for CSS (each separately): https://jsfiddle.net/6y90ktog/

Comment: You need to create something that will actually test animation, here is only preloading how do you think I can check if it's working on not. Please create 
 Minimal Working Example, just download any image that is the same size as yours, it don't need to be sprite, it only need be similar size and resolution.

Comment: I made a test image with a sprite for you https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WzPwpdTS7cz8aJKqEWV_rGPI-non_lLA/view

Comment: By minimal working example I mean code where I can see animation and it's freezing with preload.